# Random crash of system while using ubuntu 12.04 LTS with dual boot using Wubi

Tags: 12.04

I have reported a system crash and system freezing while running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.
installed Ubuntu using Wubi windows installer but faces problems every time it crash after some time shows the black screen with written that "critical temperature reached 85 c" and system go to crash. please help me to out of this problem.

MY system information

Sony Vaio VPCEA45FG(E series)

hard disk- 320 GB
logical partition for Ubuntu host is 50 GB
RAM-4 GB
Processor-Intel core i3-380M processor 2.53 GB

64 bit operating system.